# Dynamically show images from resource/drawable

Tags: android, image, sqlite, uri, android-resources

I have few images in `res/drawable` folder. I have a `SQLite` DB. I have a `GridView` where I display all the images. I select a image and fetch corresponding `URI` of the image selected. 
Now when I select the image the `URI` is displayed in `EditText`. Then I submit that message along with image. In `ListView` I display the message along with all the messages from `WebService`.

1. I need to display the corresponding image instead of `URI` in `EditText`.
2. I need to display image from EditText into Listview where i display the entire list of messages from `WebService`.

I need to submit the message in `EditText` and fetch back the same message from `WebService` along with image.

How can I achieve that?

I have done till getting the corresponding `URI` of the selected image from local `DB`. Now i need to get the image instead of `URI`.

please guide me in solving this problem.

Thanks & Regards,
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

Edit Text is for text input only.

You do not have the flexibility of showing an image.

How ever, if you have the data available with you you can try

editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(stirng));

However, if the image is remote then you will get a box.. and I don't have info how to load it from resources.